# selection statement IF won't work?

Tags: c, string

I am working through some online tutorials. I can't figure out why the IF selection statement wont work??

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char namedata[50], names;
    int n;
    printf("Enter Number of family members being enter into program \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (names=0; names<n; ++names)
    {

        printf("Enter family member name:\n");
        scanf("%s", &namedata);
        printf("name:");
        puts(namedata);

    }
    if (namedata = john)
    {
        prinf("john is cool");
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: You've got a typo; you're setting `namedata` to the value of `john`, not comparing them (`==`).

Comment: also should be using the string value (`"john"`), not the object name (`john`).

Comment: Also the variable `names` should be `int` not `char`.

Comment: You cannot compare two strings like that in C. Use `strcmp` (only if both strings are guaranteed to be properly terminated!.

Comment: Please format your code properly!

Comment: anyone using `scanf` most likely has 2 problems.

Comment: @self: could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

There are various issues in your code:

- Your `scanf` is a invitation to *undefined behaviour*, as you do not limit the number of chars to read. What if the user enters more than 49 chars?
- Always check the result of `scanf`.
- `names` has to be `int`.
- `john` should be `"john"`.
- FYI: The comparison operator is `==`, not `=`. Your compiler should actually complain! If it does not, enable warnings and compile with `-std=c99` (gcc).

Main issue: You cannot compare strings like that in C. Use `strcmp` - only if the strings are safe, else use one of the safer versions.

For the `scanf` use format specifier `%49s` to limit the input to a valid range.

Answer (score 0):

the namedata is a character array(may call it as a string) ,and u r comparing it with a string named,john .Firstly john is a string so u can't write it directly it should be with the :- " " double quotes ,Ans secondly in c you can't compare directly there is an inbuilt function called strcmp() if it returns 0 then the strings are equal.
It takes two strings as argument which u need to compare.
You can study more about it -
LINK:-[strcmp](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm)

One more thing that %s does not take fixed size so use ("%s",character array name),not like("%s",&character array name),don't use & operator with %s.

Comment: I think I understand the strcmp() however I am not seeing how I can use it for comparing a users input?? Example if the name entered is john then it will print john is cool...

Comment: if (strcmp(namedata,"john")==0)
        {
            prinf("john is cool");
        }  I hope this may satisfy you .Happy Coding ;-)